# Связь между сервисами

Tags: java, .net, asp.net, service, микросервисы

Допустим у меня есть 2 сервиса: один достает картинку с бд, второй принимает картинку и говорит что на ней изображено. Так второй сервис должен обратиться к первому. Если у меня в VS два проекта с этими сервисами, как мне обращаться с одного к другому при тестировании и отладке? Не писать же везде запрос на  localhost:*****. И после деплоя я не знаю на каком домене будут сервисы, тогда мне нужно все обращения  между сервисами переписывать на нужные домены? А если сервисов 500 и все между собой общаются? Или к примеру один сервис сменил домен, нужно везде изменять ссылки на него? Как это все происходит?

Comment: в таких случаях я использую вот эту памятку:http://blog.ginzburgconsulting.com/getting-current-page-url-or-its-parts-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

Это очень обширный вопрос. Вкратце, вы отдельно тестируете каждый сервис на предмет того, что он делает. Это т.н. модульное тестирование. Это ваш сервис для работы с БД, например. Деплой - это интеграционные тесты, они  тестируются на любой внешний адрес. Либо тестируют на рандомный порт, что прописывается, например, в аннотации типа `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`. Сервисы вообще должны быть максимально НЕ связаны.